# The mass of a solid in the shape of a hemisphere with a radius of 2 units calculated by triple integral is 0

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Q. A solid in the shape of a hemisphere with a radius of 2 units, has its base in the xy-plane and the centre of the base at the origin. If the density of the solid is given by the function ρ(x,y,z)= xyz, determine the mass of the hemisphere.

I am triple integrating the given density function, and to my surprise the mass is 0! Am I doing something wrong? Step by step solution will be highly appreciated so that I can find where I went wrong.

Thanks!

Edit-

The steps I used are-

First, I converted the Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates, then I applied triple integral over the range-

$0\le r\le 2\:  :0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi }{2}\: :0\le \phi \le 2\pi$

$\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^2\left(\:r^5sin^2\theta \:cos\phi .sin\phi .cos\theta \right)drd\theta \:d\phi$

$\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}\:}\left(\frac{16\sin ^2\left(θ\right)\cos \left(θ\right)\sin \left(2φ\right)}{3}\right)d\theta \:d\phi $

$\int _0^{2\pi \:}\left(\frac{16}{9}\sin \left(2φ\right)\right)d\phi \:=0$

Comment: By the reflexion through the $x$-axis, the mass at $(x,y,z)$ is cancelled out by the mass at $(x,-y,z)$, therefore the total mass is zero. Perhaps the density function has an absolute value on $||$?.

Comment: It’s great that you’ve already set up and solved the integral, even though it gave an unwanted answer. If you edit the question to show the integral and your steps to solve it, someone might see where things went wrong and how to fix it. For info on how to write the integral and other formulas so people can read them, look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Well, the given question doesn't tell about any absolute value of the density function at any point. Can you please elaborate your statement- I am a newbie learning the double and triple integrals.

Comment: Can you provide your step by step solution that lead to zero?

Comment: I actually looked at your function finally and Leaning is right, there is something strange here. Consider the point $(1,-1,1),$ which is inside the hemisphere. At that point $xyz=1\times-1\times1=-1.$ That is, the density there is negative. You also have negative density everywhere else above the second and fourth quadrants of the $xy$ plane. Usually we expect density to be positive, or at least zero. And yes, those densities will cancel to zero when you integrate throughout the whole hemisphere.

Comment: The cancellation comes from the symmetry of $xyz,$ and the fact that this is defined symmetrically around the origin. So, theoretically, your calculation is correct. The mass of the plate vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup in your spherical integration is not quite right, which should read,

$$\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^2
r^5 \sin^3\theta \>cos\theta\cos\phi \>\sin\phi  \>drd\theta d\phi$$

Notice that a factor $\sin\theta$ is missing in your expression.

Comment: Oh yes! I quite forgot to place the another sinθ in the expression here. Though, in my notebook I used the other sinθ. Latex typing takes some practice. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Then, you should change the result to $\int _0^{2\pi \:}\frac{4}{3}\sin 2φ d\phi $ accordingly